# LINQ Distinct from 3 tables (many to many relationship)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

First time posting here, but a long time lurker :)

I'm very new to LINQ and Entity framework and i just can't get my head around this problem, i know SQL and would write a query like this in regular sql in minutes but this is giving me a headache.

So i have 3 tables:

```
public partial class movie
{
    public int movie_id { get; set; }
    public string movie_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<playlist_movie> playlist_movie { get; set; }
}

public partial class playlist
{
    public int playlist_id { get; set; }
    public string playlist_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<playlist_movie> playlist_movie { get; set; }
}

public partial class playlist_movie
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int playlist_id { get; set; }
    public int movie_id { get; set; }
    public virtual playlist playlist { get; set; }
    public virtual movie movie { get; set; }
}
```

Now multiple movies can be in the same playlist multiple times and i can get those, but how would i go about if i wanted all the movies but with distinct playlists so i can show just what playlists the movie belongs to without duplicates?

Thanks for your help

Edit:
forgot to mention that my function returns IQueryable< movie>

Json i get:

```
{  
  "playlist_movie":[  
     {  
        "playlist":{  
           "playlist_id":1,
           "playlist_name":"test playlist"
        }
     },
     {  
        "playlist":{  
           "playlist_id":1,
           "playlist_name":"test playlist"
        }
     },
     {  
        "playlist":{  
           "playlist_id":5,
           "playlist_name":"testtest"
        }
     }
  ],
  "movie_id":5,
  "movie_name":"Test Movie"
}
```

Json i want:

```
{  
  "playlist_movie":[  
     {  
        "playlist":{  
           "playlist_id":1,
           "playlist_name":"test playlist"
        }
     },
     {  
        "playlist":{  
           "playlist_id":5,
           "playlist_name":"testtest"
        }
     }
  ],
  "movie_id":5,
  "movie_name":"Test Movie"
}
```

Comment: What would your SQL be?  It should follow same logic in c#.

Comment: i would join the 2 tables through the bridge table and then distinct that, my main problem here is that i can't get my head around the linq syntax and chaining.

Comment: So what would the SQL look like?  Don't worry about the linq syntax.  First but your thoughts on paper will what you know which is SQL.  You can get syntax at following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: will take a look at it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need to use Distinct.  You can simply use GroupBy playlist_id and take first list.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<playlist_movie> lists = new List<playlist_movie>() {
                new playlist_movie() {
                    playlist_id = 1,
                    movie_id = 5,
                    movie = new movie() { movie_id = 5, movie_name = "Test Movie"},
                    playlist = new playlist() { playlist_name = "test playlist", playlist_id = 1}
                },
                new playlist_movie() {
                    playlist_id = 1,
                    movie_id = 5,
                    movie = new movie() { movie_id = 5, movie_name = "Test Movie"},
                    playlist = new playlist() { playlist_name = "test playlist", playlist_id = 1}
                },
                new playlist_movie() {
                    playlist_id = 5,
                    movie_id = 5,
                    movie = new movie() { movie_id = 5, movie_name = "Test Movie"},
                    playlist = new playlist() { playlist_name = "testtest", playlist_id = 5}
                }


            };

            string moveie_name = "Test Movie";

            var results = lists.Where(x => x.movie.movie_name == moveie_name)
                .Select(x => new { moveie_name = x.movie.movie_name, movie_id = x.movie_id, playlist_id = x.playlist_id, playlist_name = x.playlist.playlist_name })
                .GroupBy(x => x.playlist_id)
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

        }
    }
    public partial class movie
    {
        public int movie_id { get; set; }
        public string movie_name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<playlist_movie> playlist_movie { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class playlist
    {
        public int playlist_id { get; set; }
        public string playlist_name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<playlist_movie> playlist_movie { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class playlist_movie
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int playlist_id { get; set; }
        public int movie_id { get; set; }
        public virtual playlist playlist { get; set; }
        public virtual movie movie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I modified posting to include test data.  I'm getting actual results.  There is something different with my data and your data.